# Recursive method keeps going, but in the opposite direction. Why?

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I'm trying to familiarize myself with recursion and Javascript. So I wrote a simple method to try it out. I'm pretty new to Javascript syntax so I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong. Here is the method.

```
export const IsEven = (n) => {
if(n > 1){
    n -= 2;
    IsEven(n);
}
else{
    var bool = NumberToBool(n);
    return bool;
}
```

}

When stepping through, n does reach 0 or 1 and defines it as true or false. However, the method does not stop at the return statement. Instead, it turns around and starts adding 2 to n. I cannot understand how that is even possible, does anyone have an idea on what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: not your only problem, but you are missing a `return` before `isEven(n)`.

Comment: that was it, thanks!

Comment: in general, don't mix mutation with recursion. `return isEven(n - 2)` is better than `n -= 2; return isEven(n)`

Comment: Appreciate the tip!

Comment: And the base case seems wrong. `isEven(1)` returns `NumberToBool(1)`. If I were to guess the behaviour of `NumberToBool`, that would be `true`, but `isEven(1)` should be `false`. Have you considered how it will behave if `n < 0`?

Comment: Hm, yeah you're right. I'll have to re-evaluate.

Comment: Are you stepping in a debugger?  Because I think that if it "starts adding 2 to n" you are actually witnessing it pop off the call stack of all those IsEven calls, and each time you step you may be seeing seeing the _local_ value of n get updated as you return to the caller's stack frame.  (Depends on which debugger/platform you are using.)

Comment: I'm stepping through browser developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to solve the vast majority of recursive problems -

1. if `n` is negative, return the result of `isEven(-n)`
2. (inductive) `n` is zero or greater. if `n` is greater than one, return the result of the recursive sub-problem, `isEven(n - 2)`
3. (inductive) `n` is neither negative nor greater than 1. this means `n` is **zero** or **one**. zero is even, one is odd. return `n == 0` gives us the correct result for both.

```js
const isEven = (n) => { 
  if (n < 0) return isEven(n * -1)      // 1. n is negative
  else if (n > 1) return isEven(n - 2)  // 2. n is 2 or more
  else return n == 0                    // 3. n is 0 or 1
}

for (let i = -10; i<10; i++)
  console.log(i, isEven(i))
```

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. `if` statements do not evaluate to a value and instead rely on side effects like `return` to compute the result. Below we use expressions which evaluate to a value and it allows us to skip a lot of the syntactic noise that comes with imperative style. Now `isEven` reads more like a formula -

```js
const isEven = n =>
  n < 0
    ? isEven(n * -1)   // 1. n is negative
: n > 1                
    ? isEven(n - 2)    // 2. n is 2 or more
: n == 0               // 3. n is 0 or 1

for (let i = -5; i < 5; i++)
  console.log(i, isEven(i))
```

| n | isEven(n) |
| --- | --- |
| -5 | false |
| -4 | true |
| -3 | false |
| -2 | true |
| -1 | false |
| 0 | true |
| 1 | false |
| 2 | true |
| 3 | false |
| 4 | true |

`isEven` can be defined using a synergistic counterpart, `isOdd`, where each can be defined in terms of the other. This technique is called [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) -

```js
const isEven = n =>
  n < 0
    ? isEven(-n)
: n == 0
    ? true
: isOdd(n - 1)

const isOdd = n =>
  n < 0
    ? isOdd(-n)
: n == 0
    ? false
: isEven(n - 1)

for (let i = -5; i < 5; i++)
  console.log(`i:${i} isEven:${isEven(i)} isOdd:${isOdd(i)}`)
```

| n | isEven(n) | isOdd(n) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -5 | false | true |
| -4 | true | false |
| -3 | false | true |
| -2 | true | false |
| -1 | false | true |
| 0 | true | false |
| 1 | false | true |
| 2 | true | false |
| 3 | false | true |
| 4 | true | false |